nginx avoid removing port in redirection
I'm trying to remove the .html from the URL in nginx inside a docker.
If I go to http://localhost:8080/index it works, but if I go to http://localhost:8080/index.html I want it to redirect to http://localhost:8080/index, but it's not working, it's being redirected to http:/localhost/index
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location ~* ^/(.+)\.html$ {
            set $new_uri /$1;
            return 301 $scheme://$host$new_uri;
        }

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ =404;  
        }
        
        location /css {
        root /usr/share/nginx;
    }

    location /js {
        root /usr/share/nginx;
    }

    }

    
}


Tried with rewrite and still didn't work

Try: return 301 $new_uri;

@RichardSmith still the same problem :/

The issue here is that Nginx doesn't know about port 8080, as this port is being redirected to Nginx's port 80 by Docker at the TCP level. I can suggest four different solutions:
Relative URL: You could use return 301 $new_uri;, but by default, Nginx rewrites all redirects to an absolute URL. Fortunately, it's possible to disable this behavior by adding absolute_redirect off; to your configuration. More details can be found here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#absolute_redirect.
Manual Port Specification: You can manually include the 8080 port in the redirect by using return 301 $scheme://$host:8080$new_uri;.
Consistent Port Mapping: I recommend keeping the same port numbers for both internal and external mappings in Docker. For example, your Nginx instance could listen on port 8080, and the Docker port mapping would be 8080->8080. This way, Nginx will automatically use the correct port in redirects.
Using the Host Header: The browser sends the Host: header to Nginx, which includes the port number. You can access this value using the $http_host variable in Nginx: return 301 $scheme://$http_host$new_uri;
Keep in mind that $host and $http_host are different variables. $host is always set by Nginx, while $http_host directly reflects the Host: header as it was received. If the Host: header is absent (which is a valid scenario), $http_host will be empty. You can use the map directive to handle this situation:
map $http_host $redirect_host {
  default $http_host;
  "" $host:8080;
}

